# unable to iterate the json array with key in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a json array in ts file

```
 "stocklist": {
        "1": {
            "product_name": "Chakli(500gm)",
            "item_per_bag": "22",
            "r_rate": "80",
            "in_stock_qty": "129",
            "current_requirement": 998,
            "depreciateStock": -869,
            "depreciateStockValue": -69520
        },
        "12": {
            "product_name": "Khaman mix(200gm)",
            "item_per_bag": "44",
            "r_rate": "32",
            "in_stock_qty": "301",
            "current_requirement": 521,
            "depreciateStock": -220,
            "depreciateStockValue": -7040
        }
    }
```

Which I would like to iterate in html file.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let deficit of deficitStockList;">
          <td text-center>{{ deficit.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ deficit.product_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ deficit.in_stock_qty }}</td>
          <td>{{ deficit.current_requirement }}</td>
          <td>{{ deficit.depreciateStock }}</td>
        </tr>
```

But it show error like array is not iteratable.

They key mentioned here have no use in Ionic but I can't remove it from server side.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you generate this json yourself? If so you should move the id?(1,12) inside the object.

Comment: Yes I have generated this json. But same json used in server application where key is required...

Answer (score 0):

Change your data format object to Array of Object, like mention below

```
"stocklist": [
    {
        "product_name": "Chakli(500gm)",
        "item_per_bag": "22",
        "r_rate": "80",
        "in_stock_qty": "129",
        "current_requirement": 998,
        "depreciateStock": -869,
        "depreciateStockValue": -69520
    },
    {
        "product_name": "Khaman mix(200gm)",
        "item_per_bag": "44",
        "r_rate": "32",
        "in_stock_qty": "301",
        "current_requirement": 521,
        "depreciateStock": -220,
        "depreciateStockValue": -7040
    }
]
```

Comment: You should try to provide the reason for the problem and explain your solution. SO is not for just sharing code.